# How to trigger jquery function, after inserting html table from code behind?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, code-behind

I'm working with a bootstrap template. I took the hardcoded table out of it, and now I Insert my table form codebehind.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EinschlitzsucheButton.Click

    Dim x3 As XmlElement = SearchService.FindAddressesB(login, pass, textbox.Text.ToString, False)

    Dim test = ConvertXMLToHTML(x3)

    Tablecontent.InnerHtml = test
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType(),"table_function","functiontest();", True)
```

End Sub

My problem is, that when I do this, the JQuery function does not get triggered anymore.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

    $('#MyTable').dataTable({
      "bPaginate": true,
      "bLengthChange": true,
      "bFilter": true,
      "bSort": true,
      "bInfo": true,
      "bAutoWidth": true
    });
  });
</script>
```

To be honest, I dont know much about Jquery. What can I do, to trigger the function?I need it,It gives the Table some extra options.

Cheers steven

Comment: You could try to execute a "named" javascript function from code behind using "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript" Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to execute a "named" javascript function from code behind using "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript" Method

Code behind (I use C#):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "table_function", "functionName();", true);
```

Javascript:

```
function functionName(){
   $('#MyTable').dataTable({
      "bPaginate": true,
      "bLengthChange": true,
      "bFilter": true,
      "bSort": true,
      "bInfo": true,
      "bAutoWidth": true
    });
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Hi Vinod, the question is answered in the stackoverflow style.  But I now get a exception:
DataTables warning (table id = 'Datatable1'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.
To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

Comment: Hi Steve, Please provide me more details on the error. Which line of code causes the error and so on...

Comment: Sry, was eating lunch. The exception was triggered because I had the function two times in the .aspx page. there is no more exception now. But the wanted controlls are still not added. The clientscript does not throws an exception.

Comment: Oh Ok. Do you still have problem? To know if your javascript throws any errors, open console window on your browser's developer tools. That should show you errors if any encountered runtime.

Comment: there is an exception thrown in the jquery.datables.js. As said, when i hardcode the table in the html alle table controls are added but when I insert it with innerhtml command from codebehind there is an exception in the script  thrown

Comment: OK. Possible reason could be the jquery.js might not have been loaded. Try to call function within jQuery onload. Something like this $(document).on("ready", functionName);

Comment: I guess it is because after adding the <table="datatable1"> via innerhtml command the jqery function does not find the ID yet ,because the firefox debugger gives me an element not found exception.